# DC.js - deselect feature or filter all but the ones that are clicked

Tags: charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm not sure if this is possible and no luck on researching this. I'm working on a dashboard using DC.js charts and crossfilter.js. I'm going to use a Row chart as an example. Instead of clicking on the items to filter, is it possible to do that opposite?

For example. When I click on an item from a row chart, instead of filtering on that selected item, it will deselect that item and filter the rest of the other items. And then I will keep clicking on other items to deselect.

Pretty much my goal is to implement a feature where a user can hold the 'CTRL key' and 'left click' the items in the Row Chart to deselect. This way a user dont need to click more than 50+ items in the row chart to filter and have few items not to filter.

I do have a code where Javascript detect an event where "CTRL" and "Left click" triggers. but not sure of how to filter all except the ones that are clicked.

I hope this makes sense. I tried to look at the DC.js or Crossfilter api and I cannot find a function that can do that or am i missing something.

Comment: You'll probably just want a custom `filterHandler` that uses a filter function to filter to everything that doesn't match what is in your filters. http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the same behavior except for the very first click, where you want to keep everything else and remove the clicked item if <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed.

If there is anything selected, then a click should toggle as usual, whether or not <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed.

As Ethan suggests, you could probably implement this as a `filterHandler`. That should work too, but since it's mostly the same behavior, I'd suggest using an override of `onClick`.

Unfortunately the technique for overriding this method is not pretty, but it works!

```
  var oldClick = rowChart.onClick;
  rowChart.onClick = function(d) {
      var chart = this;
      if(!d3.event.altKey)
          return oldClick.call(chart, d); // normal behavior if no mod key
      var current = chart.filters();
      if(current.length)
          return oldClick.call(chart, d); // normal behavior if there is already a selection
      current = chart.group().all()
          .map(kv => kv.key)
          .filter(k => k != d.key);
      chart.replaceFilter([current]).redrawGroup();
  };
```

I used the <kbd>alt</kbd> key instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> because <kbd>ctrl-click</kbd> on Macs is a synonym for right-click.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this on the rowcharts where I need this feature.
It's a little bit shorter than the other answer, maybe it can be useful to someone (I don't know which is better).

```
    // select only one category at a time
    mychart.onClick = function(_chart){ return function (d) {
        var filter = _chart.keyAccessor()(d);
        dc.events.trigger(function () {
            _chart.filter(null);
            _chart.filter(filter);
            _chart.redrawGroup();
        });
    }; }(mychart)
```

Where `mychart` is the name of your `dc.rowchart`

```
    var mychart = dc.rowChart('#mychart');
```

[EDIT]

This one works too, is shorter, and works with barcharts

```
    mychart.addFilterHandler(function (filters, filter) {
        filters.length = 0; // empty the array
        filters.push(filter);
        return filters;
    });
```