# how to make all bars on barchart grey on no filters selected [dc.js]

Tags: dc.js

With the current implementation of the dc.barchart, having no filters colors every bar. I basically want the "deselected" class to be on every bar if there are no filters applied. Right now I'm having trouble adding a class to a bar. What's the method for doing so?

I have tried

```
     this.chart.on('renderlet', (chart) => {
         chart.selectAll('rect.bar').classed('deselected', true);
         chart.redraw();
     });
```

But it does nothing.

From a UX perspective, the default implementation doesn't really make sense so I'm not sure why they made it that way.

Please note I'm using DC.JS

Comment: The implementation makes sense for many use cases, but yes there are lots of other possible and valid behaviors. By default it starts out with no filters, ie all rows included. Do I understand that you want to start with everything filtered out, ie everything excluded? I don't think you'd want to change the coloring without also changing the behavior.

Comment: I think it just introduces a lot of confusion when you click the bars and it removes all the colors except for the one that was clicked. If you then click every bar on the graph, the graph's "state" will have all the filters selected and show all the bars highlighted. But if you remove all the filters, the bars will all still be highlighted. It's just confusing for the end user I feel. What I want is that if all the bars are highlighted, it should mean that all the filters are selected. And if there are no filters selected, then all the bars should be grey.

Comment: It's showing which bars are included. When there are no filters, all bars are included. When there are filters, only those bars are selected. I think the colors make sense, but maybe you are looking for the behavior [where clicking always toggles instead of starting from nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118518/dc-js-deselect-feature-or-filter-all-but-the-ones-that-are-clicked)?

Comment: No, I like that clicking a filter colors the bar and deselects everything else. It's just the case when the filters are empty that I don't like. Empty filters should mean that everything is deselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you tried is a step in the right direction, but

1. It immediately redraws, cancelling itself (since the class is applied during render/redraw)
2. It would cause all bars to be grey in all cases, not just the one you care about

You're trying to change the way this function works:

```
 _chart.fadeDeselectedArea = function (selection) {
    var bars = _chart.chartBodyG().selectAll('rect.bar');

    if (_chart.isOrdinal()) {
        if (_chart.hasFilter()) {
            bars.classed(dc.constants.SELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
                return _chart.hasFilter(d.x);
            });
            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
                return !_chart.hasFilter(d.x);
            });
        } else {
            bars.classed(dc.constants.SELECTED_CLASS, false);
            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, false);
        }
    } else {
        if (!_chart.brushIsEmpty(selection)) {
            var start = selection[0];
            var end = selection[1];

            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
                return d.x < start || d.x >= end;
            });
        } else {
            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, false);
        }
    }
};
```

[(source link)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/ddbc7eb5b55d341faa90ae3579820ff20920dd58/src/bar-chart.js#L199)

Specifically, the first part, for ordinal bars.

I continue to hold that this behavior is consistent, but I'm happy to help you customize it!

I think the best way is to add a pretransition hook which just adds the deselected class to all bars when there are no filters. (You could also override the function but then you'd have to duplicate the has-filters logic.)

This turns out to be really easy:

```
barChart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    var bars = chart.chartBodyG().selectAll('rect.bar');
    if (chart.hasFilter()) {
        bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, true);
    }
});
```

(The `selected` class doesn't do anything for bar charts, so we can ignore it.)

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/yb514vum/12/)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to do this! this is exactly what I need