# Unable to properly synchronize dcjs chart and regular bootstrap multi select with filters

Tags: dc.js

[Please see this pen](https://codepen.io/rdavi10471a2/project/editor/XwGGYo)

I am attempting to synchronize the select menu's  with the filters in the sales by branch chart.
if you filter the chart the select menu has its filters changed but if you try the other way  the multi-select fails to work correctly after removing the first filter.

has anyone made anything similar work.
I have a feeling that I am doing something stupid.. cause this should not be this hard

here is the on change for the select menu

```
 $('#branchselect').selectpicker('refresh')
     $('#branchselect').on("change",function(){
      console.log("on chanage")      
          var filters = [];
       //fromonchange =true;
          $.each($("#branchselect option:selected"), function(){
            filters.push($(this).val());
          });
      console.log(" on change dd Filters")
      console.log(filters)
       console.log("on  change chart filters")
      console.log(salesbybranch.filters())
       bfilter  =[]   
      bfilter[0] = filters
      salesbybranch.filter(bfilter)
      dc.redrawAll()
});
```

I don't see what is causing the select to start acting like a single select unless it is the toggle nature of how the chart filters work?

The easiest way to see the difference in behavior is to note that both the select and the chart start with all items selected. then start deselecting/selecting items in the chart and note that the select stays in sync.
reload the page and then try the same from the select after the second branch is deselected all items but the last clicked item are deselected.

Comment: There is a feedback loop going on here that I can't seem to get out of. I tried detecting the situation but my flag setting did not work. see commented out code testing for fromonchange

Comment: the attempt to make this work continues.  selecting a single row from the branch sales chart will remove the check  from the associated item in the dropdown.  selecting the item from the dropdown  does not re-enable the item in the chart.  not sure why this is the case

Comment: part of the problem here is the differeing behavior on the chart with respect to clicks. the first click deselects everything but that item every click after that toggles. why is this?

Comment: It's tricky using codepen for SO questions because it doesn't have versioning. Looks like this is the same pen as in the other question, and it's been fixed not to use selectMenu at all... Maybe it would be a good idea to fork the pen before continuing work that might invalidate the question. I mildly prefer jsFiddles or bl.ocks because they are versioned (but no big deal).

Comment: To answer your question, there are a number of ways that selection might work. I think the original idea was that users often want to single in on one item. From a programming perspective, sure, this is more complicated than always toggling, but what's simple for programmers is not always what is simple for users.

Comment: It would be nice to have [better primitives to allow a whole range of filtering behaviors](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/716). See this question for a way to always toggle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118518/dc-js-deselect-feature-or-filter-all-but-the-ones-that-are-clicked/49241400#49241400

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will check it out.. and as always *Fixed* is the operative word the latest version of the PEN does appear to work except for the first for the single branch selection....